# Vim: Run command for `n` lines

Tags: vim, text

Let's start with an example.

I have a text document that I'm editing. It is of the form:

```
**** A
**** B
**** C
 ...
**** Z
```

I want to carry out the operation `3x` which (on L0 C0) yields: `* A`

Is there a quick way to tell VIM: Run this command `3x` within line range (m, n)

Comment: `3x` to repeat it in which position of each line ?

Comment: You can use `:m,n normal! 3x`  with `m,n` is the range but note that it will delete the first 3 characters of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Visual block to easily choose the lines you want to edit :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>I</kbd> to enter insert mode at the start of the line , and when you finish editing hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then All the selected lines will be affected .

Answer (score 0):

i would record a macro, then run it twice.
lets suppose your doc looks like this

```
*** A
*** B
*** C
*** D
```

and you want it like this

```
ooo A
ooo B
ooo C
*** D
```

go to the first line `gg0` and hit `qq` to begin recording a macro. then work as usual `cwooo<esc>` then go down one line `j0` and hit `q` to stop recording. now just run the macro twice with `2@q`